# Apache Ignite org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Invalid handshake message

Tags: ignite, gridgain

org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Invalid handshake message

I am getting this exception on dev environment. But on research environment it is working fine.
Can somebody tell me what is the exact reason for this exception.
The full logs are below.

```
2020-01-20 19:21:35.852 ERROR 6 --- [-listener-3-#32] o.a.i.i.p.odbc.ClientListenerProcessor   : Closing NIO session because of unhandled exception.
org.apache.ignite.IgniteCheckedException: Invalid handshake message
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerNioServerBuffer.read(ClientListenerNioServerBuffer.java:114) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerBufferedParser.decode(ClientListenerBufferedParser.java:59) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.processors.odbc.ClientListenerBufferedParser.decode(ClientListenerBufferedParser.java:39) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioCodecFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioCodecFilter.java:113) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterAdapter.proceedMessageReceived(GridNioFilterAdapter.java:108) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$HeadFilter.onMessageReceived(GridNioServer.java:3575) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioFilterChain.onMessageReceived(GridNioFilterChain.java:174) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$ByteBufferNioClientWorker.processRead(GridNioServer.java:1150) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.processSelectedKeysOptimized(GridNioServer.java:2411) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.bodyInternal(GridNioServer.java:2178) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.nio.GridNioServer$AbstractNioClientWorker.body(GridNioServer.java:1819) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:119) ~[ignite-core-8.7.5.jar!/:8.7.5]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

I am using 8.7.5 version of grid gain and 2.7.5 version of apache ignite.
We are using kubernetes.

Comment: I'm not sure there is full protocol compatibility between Apache Ignite and GridGain. Why do you have to use both? Have you tried using only one of these? What kind of client do you use?

Comment: I will try. And this exception conning on ignite server . And no client have been deployed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is definitely some software trying to connect to port 10800 or 11211. You should check that you have no software in your local network tries to talk to all ports frivolously.

Also, does it cause any problems?

I assume that you don't have any thin clients running, only Ignite server/client nodes.

Comment: Yup some other application was trying to hit the ignite port.

Comment: We've seen this when someone forgot and left Visor connected